# What will happen to Firebase Cloud Functions after deactivating Node.js 8?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using the Spark plan in an application with Node.js 8. What will happen to Cloud Functions after disabling this version in the Spark plan? Will I be forced to upgrade the plan to use the module?

Answer (score 2):

Node 8 will no longer be supported on Cloud Functions, no matter what plan your project is on.

It is already impossible to deploy Node 8 code through the Firebase CLI and per March 15, 2021 the Cloud Functions will also no longer be invoked/callable.

If you want to continue to run your Cloud Functions after that time you will have to upgrade your Cloud Functions runtime to Node 10 or later, and will have to have a billing account associated with your Google Cloud project, or be on the Firebase paid plan.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue running the function, you will be required to both upgrade to the paid plan and also upgrade your function to node 10 by March 15.

I suggest reviewing the [FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#cloud-functions).